# Deep learning with TENSORFLOW: Issues with saving and loading models

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

**Contextualization**
I am building a model for image recognition with tensorfow. In fact, I am trying to save my model then restore it in order to make prediction.

**Procedure**
I built a CNN with this structure

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 204, 204, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 204, 204, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 204, 204, 32)      9248      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 102, 102, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 332928)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 512)               170459648 
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 39)                20007     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 39)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 170,489,799
Trainable params: 170,489,799
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I saved my graph and variables within a saver. I purposefully named my placeholders **X** and **Y**, and named the prediction (which is an operation): **output**. The purpose of naming them is to be able to restore them and use them for prediciton.

**What I have done**

1. To build and train my model, I first defined my placeholders and constructed the computational graph.
2. Then, I defined a saver where the graph and variables are saved.
3. After that, I trained my network ( I used 1 epoch because i wanted to try if saving and restoring is working fine). and then i saved the session variables values in the saver and exported the saver in a folder , so that I can restore it later. Before closing the tensorflow session. I calculated the prediciton in the end of the first epoch and I wanted to compare it with the result from a restored session.
4. I restored/reloaded the graph & variables ( which I saved in the previous operation).
5. I restored  saved placeholders ( **X** and **Y**) and the operation "**output**"  in order the calculate prediction with the same data used in the end of the first training epoch. " the purpose is to be sure that save&restore procedure works fine) .  So when I calculated the prediction i got a **None** value ? I don't get what is wrong with my method.

**Here is the code I used**

Defining & designing the model structure

```
def create_model(X,Y):
    # Convolutional Layer #1
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=X,
      filters=32,
      kernel_size=[3, 3],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)
    print('conv1 OUTPUT shape: ',conv1.shape)

    # Dropout layer #1
    dropout1 = tf.layers.dropout(
      inputs=conv1, rate=0.2, training='TRAIN' == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    print('drop1 OUTPUT shape: ',dropout1.shape)

    # Convolutional Layer #2
    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=dropout1,
      filters=32,
      kernel_size=[3, 3],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)
    print('conv2 OUTPUT shape: ',conv2.shape)

    # Pooling Layer #2
    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2],strides=2)
    print('pool2 OUTPUT shape: ',pool2.shape)
    pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, pool2.shape[1]*pool2.shape[2]*pool2.shape[3]])

    # Dense layer #3
    dense3 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    print('dense3 OUTPUT shape: ',dense3.shape)

    # Dropout layer #3
    dropout3 = tf.layers.dropout(
      inputs=dense3, rate=0.5, training='TRAIN' == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    print('drop3 OUTPUT shape: ',dropout3.shape)

    # Dense layer #4
    Z = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout3, units=39, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
    print('dense4 OUTPUT shape: ',Z.shape)

    #Threshold
    #Z1 = tf.to_int32(Z > 0.5)
    #print('OUTPUT: shape output after threshold ',Z1.shape)

    # Calculating cost
    cost= tf.reduce_mean(Y * - tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(Z,1e-10,1.0)) + (1 - Y) * - tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(1 - Z,1e-10,1.0)),axis=0)
    print('cost: shape of cost: ',cost.shape)
    cost= tf.reshape(cost, [1, 39])
    print('cost reshaped: shape of cost reshaped: ',cost.shape)
    #Optimizer
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)
    #Metric paramaters 
    predicted_positive = predicted_positives(Y,Z)
    true_and_possible_positive = true_and_possible_positives(Y,Z)
    #naming operations
    output1=tf.multiply(Z,1,name='the_output_for_prediction')
    cost1=tf.multiply(cost,1,name='cost')
    return output1,predicted_positive,true_and_possible_positive,optimizer,cost1
```

creating model & training & saving & evaluating prediction after first epoch( works fine)

```
# For a given (X_train,Y_train)&(X_valid,Y_train) and some hyperparam( some cannot be changed: it trains a model, saves it and returns the metric values.

#def train_model(X_train,Y_train,X_valid,Y_valid,num_epochs,minibatch_size=32):
#Reset tensorflow graph
ops.reset_default_graph()

# hyperparameters
num_epochs=1
minibatch_size=32

m=X_train.shape[0]

#Initialize metric variables
costs = []
precision=[]
recall=[]
costs_v = []
precision_v=[]
recall_v=[]

m=X_train.shape[0]



#Placeholders
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2],X_train.shape[3]],name="X")
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, Y_train.shape[1]],name="Y")

#Graph construction
output,predicted_positives,true_and_possible_positives,optimizer,cost=create_model(X,Y)

# Initializer for all the variables globally
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

#Creating tf session and running it (i.e initialize the global variables) 
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

# Create model saver
#model_saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver = tf.train.Saver()




#Training algorithm
#Running epochs
for epoch in range(num_epochs):

            ########################################### training   ################################################
            print('training epoch number :',epoch)

            #initialize parameters of metrics 
            predicted_po=0
            true_po=0
            possible_po=0

            #initialize cost param and mini_batches
            minibatch_cost = 0.
            num_minibatches = int(m / minibatch_size) # number of minibatches of size minibatch_size in the train set
            minibatches = random_mini_batches(X_train, Y_train, minibatch_size)
            #Running batches
            for minibatch in minibatches:

                #minibatch extraction
                minibatch_X=X_train[minibatch,]
                minibatch_Y=Y_train[minibatch,]

                # IMPORTANT: The line that runs the graph on a minibatch.
                # Run the session to execute the optimizer, cost and metric parameters , the feedict should contain a minibatch for (X,Y).
                _ , temp_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X:minibatch_X, Y:minibatch_Y})
                predicted_p,true_p_p = sess.run([predicted_positives, true_and_possible_positives], feed_dict={X:minibatch_X, Y:minibatch_Y})

                #calculate cost,predicted_true_possible positives per batch.
                minibatch_cost += temp_cost / num_minibatches
                predicted_po+=predicted_p
                true_po+=true_p_p[0]
                possible_po+=true_p_p[1]

                #print batch param metric
                    #print('predicted_p per batch ',noi,'  ',predicted_p)
                    #print('true_p per bartch ',noi,'  ',true_p_p[0])
                    #print('possible_p per batch ',noi,'  ',true_p_p[1])


            '''
            # Print the cost every epoch
            #    print ("Cost after epoch %i: %f" % (epoch, minibatch_cost))
            print('precision_on_training epoch: ',epoch,'  ',true_po/predicted_po)
            print('recall on training epoch ',epoch,'  ', true_po/possible_po)
            '''


            #appending tables of costs and metrics on training
            costs.append(minibatch_cost)
            precision.append(true_po/predicted_po)
            recall.append(true_po/possible_po)

            minibatches=None
            minibatch_X=None
            minibatch_Y=None
            ###################################### Validation  ###################################################

            print('validation epoch number :',epoch)

            #create minibatches for validation
            #initialize parameters of metrics 

            m_v=X_valid.shape[0]
            minibatch_cost_v = 0.
            num_minibatches_v = int(m_v / minibatch_size) # number of minibatches validation of size minibatch_size_v in the validation set
            predicted_po_v=0
            true_po_v=0
            possible_po_v=0
            minibatches_valid=random_mini_batches(X_valid, Y_valid, minibatch_size)



            #running batches
            for minibatch in minibatches_valid:
                #print('batch validation number ', noi_v, ' / ',num_minibatches_v)
                minibatch_X_valid=X_train[minibatch,]
                minibatch_Y_valid=Y_train[minibatch,]
                temp_cost_v = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X:minibatch_X_valid, Y:minibatch_Y_valid})
                predicted_p_v,true_p_p_v = sess.run([predicted_positives, true_and_possible_positives], feed_dict={X:minibatch_X_valid, Y:minibatch_Y_valid})

                minibatch_cost_v += temp_cost_v / num_minibatches_v
                predicted_po_v+=predicted_p_v
                true_po_v+=true_p_p_v[0]
                possible_po_v+=true_p_p_v[1]

            '''
            #Printing precision and recall on validation
            print('precision_on_validation epoch: ',epoch,'  ',true_po_v/predicted_po_v)
            print('recall on validation epoch ',epoch,'  ', true_po_v/possible_po_v)    
            '''

            #appending tables of costs and metrics on training
            costs_v.append(minibatch_cost_v)
            precision_v.append(true_po_v/predicted_po_v)
            recall_v.append(true_po_v/possible_po_v)    
            minibatches_valid=None   
            minibatch_X_valid=None
            minibatch_Y_valid=None


#A simple test to check whether a restored model has exactly the same values (w and graph) as the original. Testing on a new output.
prediction_first_epoch=sess.run([output], feed_dict={X:X_train[[0]], Y:Y_train[[0]]})
print(np.mean(prediction_first_epoch))


#Save model            
#global_step: used for checkpoints 
saver.save(sess, 'ok/',global_step=1000)


##Save different training parameters.
costs_array=np.asarray(costs)
precision_array=np.asarray(precision)
recall_array=np.asarray(recall)
costs_v_array=np.asarray(costs_v)
precision_v_array=np.asarray(precision_v)
recall_v_array=np.asarray(recall_v)
np.save('costs_array', costs_array)
np.save('precision_array', precision_array)
np.save('recall_array', recall_array)
np.save('costs_v_array', costs_v_array)
np.save('precision_v_array', precision_v_array)
np.save('recall_v_array', recall_v_array)





sess.close()
```

Restoring saved model and trying to predict with same data as before

```
ops.reset_default_graph()
sess=tf.Session()   
#Load meta_graph and restore weights
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('ok/-1000.meta')
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('ok/'))
#put graph in variable and load adequate tensors & operations
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
X = graph.get_tensor_by_name("X:0")
Y = graph.get_tensor_by_name("Y:0")
output=graph.get_operation_by_name("the_output_for_prediction")
output_vis= sess.run(output, feed_dict={X:X_train[[0]], Y:Y_train[[0]]})

print(output_vis)
sess.close()
```

Result:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ok/-1000
None
```

**Question**

I don't understand why am I getting None value even though I restored the saved graph in the default graph and extracted the two placeholders and the operation for prediction.

Answer (score 0):

[Issue solved]
I am calling the operation, that's why I am getting a none value.
Instead, i need to call the tensor associated with that operation and feed it with input.
So instead of doing this:

```
output=graph.get_operation_by_name("the_output_for_prediction")
```

I should have done this:

```
output=graph.get_tensor_by_name("the_output_for_prediction:0")
```

PS: the ":0" is so important. If you write "the_output_for_prediction" , this won't work!